# GCC Make Code or Section have Read Write and Execute properties

Tags: c++, gcc, segment

I need to be able to write to a function as well as execute it, such as that this code (or similar) would run without crashing:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int function(int i) {
    i = i * 56;
    printf("%i\n",i);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("before\n");
    function(5);
    *(int*)function = 0;
    printf("after");
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be

```
before
280
after
```

To where the line `*(int*)function = 0;` does not crash the program because of the write proections to function.
The limitations are that I cannot use `mprotect` or `VirtualProtect`, so my best guess is something to do with GCC's `__attribute__` modifier. I have managed to use the `section` attribute to change it from `.text` to `.data` however that only allows write or exeute, neither have both properties at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `__attribute__((section(".tdata")))` before the function seems to have solved the issues.